# Laravel insert multiple row in pivot table for one relational id for clone fields

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship, one-to-many

I have two relational tables with pivot `routes`, `stations`, and `route_station`. The `routes` table contains the route number for the metro, and the `stations` contains all the stations.

The **pivot table** multiple routes and multiple stations for each route. So not sure how to consider it. Either `many-to-many` or `one-to-many`?

### HTML Form

The HTML form on the `Route` contains clonable fields that need to insert into the pivot table. See below.

- Station
- Next Station
- Distance
- Duration

### The Question

> So my question is how to insert clonable fields data (in the above
> list) so that insert row in the **pivot** table for each cloned field?
>
> Also how I can update so it updates the exact record in the pivot
> table and if the clone field is removed then the record from the pivot
> table also removes?

### Route Schema

```
Schema::create(
    'routes',
    function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->smallInteger('number')->unsigned()->unique();
        $table->string('code')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unique(['number', 'code'], 'routes_unique_columns');
    }
);
```

## Station Schema

```
Schema::create(
    'stations',
    function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name')->index()->unique();
        $table->string('code')->index()->unique();
        $table->text('info');
        $table->string('photo')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    }
);
```

## Route Station (Pivot) Schema

```
Schema::create(
    'route_station',
    function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('route_id')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('station_id')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('next_station_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('station_order');
        $table->float('distance');
        $table->integer('duration');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unique(['route_id', 'station_id'], 'route_station_unique');

        $table->foreign('route_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('routes')
              ->onDelete('restrict');

        $table->foreign('station_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('stations')
              ->onDelete('restrict');

        $table->foreign('next_station_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('stations')
              ->onDelete('restrict');
    }
);
```

## Route Create/Update Form

[image]

## Update

I have tried below but not working. Giving `Array to String conversion` error. This is because, I believe the `attach` and `sync` is inserting only one record, while the request fields is an array.

So how can I insert a record for each item of an array?

```
$route = Route::create([
    'number' => $request->number,
    'code'   => strtoupper($request->code),
]);

$route->stations()->sync($route, [
    'next_station_id' => $request->next_station_id,
    'distance'        => $request->distance,
    'duration'        => $request->duration,
    'station_order'   => $request->station_order,
]);
```

Comment: Here is something that can help you, just pick the correct laravel version https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1):

So as i can see for one route section you have one starting station and one ending station so you can consider this a one to one relationship.

By route section i mean one row of the route_station table.

One route section => one starting station, one ending section.

Second route section => second starting station, second ending station.

You can consider it one to one for each route_station.station_id to stations.id and route_station.next_station_id to stations.id

With this you can take the start and next station for every route_station.
So in the route_station table you can have one to one relationship for the station_id field to the stations table and another one to one relationship for the next_station_id field to the stations table

On the other hand you have one route to many route_stattions (many routing sections)  with this you can take all the route_stattions for one route.
So in the routes table you can have a one to many relationship on the field routes.id with the table route_stations and the field route_stations.route_id

You can read more about the laravel relationships on the link

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Make sure you select the correct laravel version

You can insert the values model by model for each table.

You just need to make sure you get the correct ids for tge foreign fields for each record.

You can also update the data model by model separatelly as well but you first need get the table row id that needs to be updated.

You can read more about updating the model on this link
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#updates

Comment: If ithis solved your problem, can you sign my answer as answer for this question

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation and reference link. That will help me.

Comment: Please have a look at my updated code in question. I am having trouble inserting multiple fields record.

Comment: I do t think you can use sync in thsi case. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships. You can just insert in the table just as you do in the route table above.

Comment: `sync` was just a try. `attach` is not working either. I have followed the doc but didn't help me. My issue is probably different. I want to create multiple records submitting one form request from the clonable fields. However, the doc shows inserting one record at a time.

Comment: Yes you need to insert the records one at a time. You need to make another logic so that you know how many fields were cloned on the front end so that you send that paremeter probably in a hidden field. On backend you can take this parameter and you will know how many records to create in db. Also you can name the front end fields with row number in the name so that you can take them in backend. Hope this helps